# How does JobScheduler know if a job has failed for it to retry?

Tags: android, android-service, android-jobscheduler

I have a periodic job scheduled using android's `JobScheduler`

```
val serviceComponent = ComponentName(context, BackupJobService::class.java)
        val builder = JobInfo.Builder(0, serviceComponent)
        builder.setPeriodic(thirtyMins)
        val jobScheduler = context.getSystemService(JobScheduler::class.java)
        val job = builder.build()
        jobScheduler.schedule(job)
```

The documentation says that the default retry mechanism for a failing job is an exponential back-off. But how does `JobScheduler` know if `BackupJobService` succeed or failed? In my case, especially, the `BackupJobService` spawns a `JobIntentService` to do the job.

Answer (score 1):

> The documentation says that the default retry mechanism for a failing job is an exponential back-off.

Actually it depends on return value when you override method `onStopJob` and the way you call method `jobFinished (JobParameters params, boolean wantsReschedule)`. If you already call `jobFinished` with `wantsReschedule` value `false` or `onStopJob` return `false` Android not retry your work.

Check documents [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobService#onStopJob(android.app.job.JobParameters))